# converging sequence $x_{n+1} = x_n f(x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

let $f: [0,+\infty[ \rightarrow [0,1[$ a continuous fonction and ($x_n$) a sequence defined by
$$x_{n+1} = x_nf(x_n) \text{ and } x_0 = 1$$

1. show $x_n$ converges
2. calculate its limit.

What I have done so far:

$$x_{n+1}-x_n  = x_nf(x_n)-x_{n-1}f(x_{n-1}) = f(x_n)f(x_{x-1})x_{n-1} - f(x_{n-1})f(x_{n-2})x_{n-2}$$
$$=...=f(x_n)f(x_{n-1})...f(x_1)x_1 - f(x_{n-1})...f(x_1)f(x_0)x_0 = [f(x_{n-1})...f(x_1)](f(x_n)x_1-f(x_0)x_0)$$
$$ = [f(x_{n-1})...f(x_1)](f(x_n)f(1)-f(1))= [f(x_{n-1})...f(x_1)f(1)](f(x_n)-1)$$
$$0\leq f(x) < 1 \Longrightarrow x_{n+1}-x_n < 0 \Longrightarrow x_n \text{ is a decreasing sequence}$$
Furthermore $0\leq x_n$, hence $x_n$ converges to its infinimum.

for number 2 I'm not sure if the reasoning is correct:

suppose ($x_n) \longrightarrow l$ then
$$l = \lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty} x_{n+1} = lf(l) $$
$f(l) < 1 \Longrightarrow  l=0$

Comment: looks fine to me. You can conclude that $x_n$ is decreasing immediately from $x_{n+1} = x_nf(x_n) < x_n.$

Comment: [Decreasing and bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part $(1)$, I would just note that $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=f(x_n)\in[0,1)$.

With $x_0=1$ (or simply $>0$), this sequence is always positive and decreasing (unless $\exists t\in \Bbb N : f(x_t)=0$, in which case the sequence immediately becomes a sequence of $0$s thereafter)

Your reasoning for part $(2)$ is absolutely correct.